# 50k files realm DB load in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I am using Realm for my application, I have a DB of 50k files.

```
 let results: Results<File> = realm.objects(File.self)
```

I am loading the results into UITableView.
It is hanging not all smooth scroll is happening, Any suggestions how can I load lazily to provide better performanced UI.

Comment: implement lazy load

Comment: Realm lazy loads records anyway. so realm is unlikely to be the cause. more likely to be the tableView implementation. which we can't help you with as you haven't provided any code

Comment: Had you found a solution earlier?